# Firebase user display name won't show on activity after creating new Firebase email password user account?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I make an sign up activity to create new user on Firebase using Simple Email Password shown below

[CreateAccountActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cB2L.png)

public class CreateAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog mprogress;
private RelativeLayout signUpactivity;

FirebaseUser user;

private Button msignUp;
public EditText mName,mEmail,mPassword,mCon_Password,mschl_name;

Spinner gender;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_creat_acc);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mprogress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    msignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);

    signUpactivity = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_signUp);

    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namefield);
    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    mschl_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sname);

    String[] option = new String[]{
            "Male", "Female"
    };

    gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, option);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gender.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    msignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isNetworkAvailable()){

                mprogress.setMessage("Creating Account...");
                mprogress.show();
                mprogress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mprogress.setCancelable(false);
                createAccount();

            }else{

                Snackbar.make(signUpactivity, "Network UnAvailable", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();

}

View focusview = null;
boolean cancel = false;

private void createAccount(){

    final String name = mName.getText().toString();
    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

    String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
    final String gendertxt = gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String schl_name = mschl_name.getText().toString();

    String edu_email = email+"@edutree.com";

        if (isNetworkAvailable()){

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edu_email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        user =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        String user_email = user.getEmail();
                        String gendertxt = gender.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(name).build(); 

                        user.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Log.d("Profile", "User Profile Updated successfully");
                                    FirebaseCrash.log("Profile Updated");

                                }else {

                                    Log.d("Error","error while updating profile");
                                    FirebaseCrash.log("Error while updating profile");

                                }

                            }
                        });


                        mprogress.dismiss();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

                                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Welcome "+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },500);


                    }else{

                        Snackbar.make(signUpactivity, "Error occurred" , Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mprogress.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });

        }else {

            Snackbar.make(signUpactivity, "Network UnAvailable", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mprogress.dismiss();

        }

}
```

}

When user enters the information it start method CreateAccount() and then when task is successful it updates user profile and set the display name and Starts the MainActivity. but it starts the MainActivty its not showing the user name.

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP5ZW.png)

Can Anyone help me to fix this problem, and when user get sign out and sign in again then it shows the name otherwise it didn't show after Sign up.

**Any Answers were highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code that starts MainActivity to inside the onComplete() method for the profile change.  Right now your code starts the Firebase user profile change to store the display name, but it shows MainActivity before that user profile change is completed.

You can update this piece of your code, look at what I added at the end of the onComplete() method:

```
user.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Log.d("Profile", "User Profile Updated successfully");
                                    FirebaseCrash.log("Profile Updated");

                                }else {

                                    Log.d("Error","error while updating profile");
                                    FirebaseCrash.log("Error while updating profile");

                                }

                                mprogress.dismiss();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Welcome "+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });
```

Then, you can remove this code later in the function:

```
mprogress.dismiss();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

                                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Welcome "+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },500);
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include details of where to move which code.

Comment: When I turn it off and turn it on again it still does not work, but when I sign out the user and re-sign it then it's work